# Need to get the value of the element tag when parsing XML with SAX Parser

Tags: android, xml, parsing, tags, sax

Grabbing an XML file off of the internet and feeding it's data into a database.  Most of it works just fine.  But I have a problem with xml tags having the same name but different values attached.

So, we have an xml file like this:

```html
<Overtag>
  <Tag> Name </Tag>
  <SubTag> TextSubTag </SubTag>
  <TagWithValue value="SomeValue"> TextTagWithValue </TagWithValue>
</Overtag>
<Overtag>...
```

I can set up a NodeList by Overtag.  I can get a nodeist of Overtag's Children which I call Children.

So, I run this over a for loop - for(int nN=0; nN

I grab the Text of the Tags themselves:

String sTag = Children.item(nN).getNodeName();

I can even grab the text between the Tags: 
Children.item(nN).getTextContent()

BUT I need to organize this text based on the value.

What command can I use to get "SomeValue" if nN = the childlist number for  (in this case 2)?

As in:  Children.item(nN).?

Answer (score 0):

Found it...

if using NodeList to list out your xml tags, you need to return it to an element, then use getAttribute; so if the tag is   (assuming your list with TagWithValue in it is a NodeList called Children):

```
Element eChild = (Element) Children.item(nN);
                String sAtt = eChild.getAttribute("value");`
```

This will give you sAtt = "SomeValue".  Sorry to waste space by posting then finding the answer two hours later; hopefully someone else finds this useful.